# MySQL - SELECT WHERE field IN (subquery) - Extremely slow why?

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-in

I've got a couple of duplicates in a database that I want to inspect, so what I did to see which are duplicates, I did this:

```
SELECT relevant_field
FROM some_table
GROUP BY relevant_field
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This way, I will get all rows with relevant_field occuring more than once. This query takes milliseconds to execute.

Now, I wanted to inspect each of the duplicates, so I thought I could SELECT each row in some_table with a relevant_field in the above query, so I did like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table 
WHERE relevant_field IN
(
    SELECT relevant_field
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY relevant_field
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

This turns out to be extreeeemely slow for some reason (it takes minutes). What exactly is going on here to make it that slow? relevant_field is indexed.

Eventually I tried creating a view "temp_view" from the first query `(SELECT relevant_field FROM some_table GROUP BY relevant_field HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`, and then making my second query like this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE relevant_field IN
(
    SELECT relevant_field
    FROM temp_view
)
```

And that works just fine. MySQL does this in some milliseconds.

Any SQL experts here who can explain what's going on?

Comment: what u exact want? want to delete Duplicate entries except one??  Suggestion: please Read [Self Join](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/MySQL-Table-Joins/4/)

Comment: obviously is the group-by that is slow ...

Comment: The first query executes in milliseconds (the one grouping and filtering with HAVING). It's only in combination with the other query which makes everything slow (it takes minutes).

Comment: @diEcho, I want to find duplicates, inspect them, and delete some manually.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The subquery is being run for each row because it is a correlated query. One can make a correlated query into a non-correlated query by selecting everything from the subquery, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT relevant_field
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY relevant_field
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS subquery
```

The final query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE relevant_field IN
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT relevant_field
        FROM some_table
        GROUP BY relevant_field
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS subquery
)
```

Comment: This worked amazingly well for me. I had another IN(subquery) within a IN(subquery), and it was taking more than 10 minutes, so long that I googled while I was waiting. Wrapping each subquery in SELECT * FROM () as you suggested reduced it to 2 seconds!

Comment: THANK YOU, I've been trying to figure out a good way to do this for a couple hours now. This worked perfectly. Wish I could give you more upvotes! This should definitely be the answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. A query that took ~50secs to run is now instantaneous. Wish I could upvote more. Sometimes you cannot use joins so this is the right answer.

Comment: I wonder why the optimizer considers queries with unions correlated... Anyway, this trick worked like magic

Comment: Could you please explain what makes that a correlated subquery? My understanding that subquery becomes correlated, when it uses a value that depends on the outer query. But in this example I cannot see any interdependencies. It'd give the same result for each row returned by the outer query. I have a similar example being implemented on MariaDB and I can see no performance hit (so far), so I'd like to see clearly, when this `SELECT *` wrapping is needed.

Answer (score 119):

Rewrite the query into this

```
SELECT st1.*, st2.relevant_field FROM sometable st1
INNER JOIN sometable st2 ON (st1.relevant_field = st2.relevant_field)
GROUP BY st1.id  /* list a unique sometable field here*/
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

*I think `st2.relevant_field` must be in the select, because otherwise the `having` clause will give an error, but I'm not 100% sure*

Never use `IN` with a subquery; this is notoriously slow.
Only ever use `IN` with a fixed list of values.

**More tips**

1. If you want to make queries faster,
   don't do a `SELECT *` only select
   the fields that you really need.
2. Make sure you have an index on `relevant_field` to speed up the equi-join.
3. Make sure to `group by` on the primary key.
4. If you are on InnoDB **and** you only select indexed fields *(and things are not too complex)* than MySQL will resolve your query using only the indexes, speeding things way up.

**General solution for 90% of your `IN (select`  queries**

Use this code

```
SELECT * FROM sometable a WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM sometable b
  WHERE a.relevant_field = b.relevant_field
  GROUP BY b.relevant_field
  HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: You can also write that with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. It's usually faster in MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube, done for the bottom query, I think that for the top query it will alter the outcome.

Comment: @Johan: Since `st2.relevant_field` is not `NULL` (it's already included in the `ON` clause), it won't alter the result.

Comment: @ypercube, so you can change count(afield) into count(*) **if** you're sure `afield` will never be `null`, got it. Thanks

Comment: Does this actually list all duplicates? Not just one of each duplicate.

Comment: @quano, yes it lists **all** duplicates because the `group by` is on `st1.id`, not on `st1.relevant_field`.

Comment: Hi, any of you guys want to attempt to help me solve this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143383/user-variable-in-nested-subquery-not-getting-picked-up-in-complex-sort-of-2-ta  ?

Comment: slow too. 47 seconds on query.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT st1.*
FROM some_table st1
inner join 
(
    SELECT relevant_field
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY relevant_field
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)st2 on st2.relevant_field = st1.relevant_field;
```

I've tried your query on one of my databases, and also tried it rewritten as a join to a sub-query.

This worked a lot faster, try it!

Comment: Yes, this will probably create a temp table with the group results, so it will be same speed as the view version. But the query plans should tell the truth.

Answer (score 6):

I have reformatted your slow sql query with www.prettysql.net

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE
 relevant_field in
 (
  SELECT relevant_field
  FROM some_table
  GROUP BY relevant_field
  HAVING COUNT ( * ) > 1
 );
```

When using a table in both the query and the subquery, you should always alias both, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table as t1
WHERE
 t1.relevant_field in
 (
  SELECT t2.relevant_field
  FROM some_table as t2
  GROUP BY t2.relevant_field
  HAVING COUNT ( t2.relevant_field ) > 1
 );
```

Does that help?

Comment: It does unfortunately not help. It executes just as slow.

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try again? Even if the group by is slow, it should be executed only once...

Comment: I accidentally killed a live mysql server last time, so I'm afraid I can't try this right now. I'll have to set up a test database later. But I don't understand why this should affect the query. The HAVING statement should only apply to the query which it's within, shouldn't it? I really don't understand why the "real" query should affect the subquery.

Comment: I found this: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/ . I think this might be the solution. Will try when I get time.

Answer (score 6):

[Subqueries vs joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins)

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2546837/New-Subquery-Optimizations-In-MySQL-6

Comment: I suspected something like this, that the subquery is being run for each row.

Comment: Some MySQL Version even don't use an Index in IN. I've added another link.

Comment: MySQL 6 is not stable yet, I would not recommend that for production!

Comment: I would not recommend it. But here is explained how it runs internally (4.1/5.x -> 6). This demonstrates some pitfalls of the current versions.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly  you can find duplicate rows and find count of rows is used how many times and order it by number like this;

```html
SELECT q.id,q.name,q.password,q.NID,(select count(*) from UserInfo k where k.NID= q.NID) as Count,
(
  CASE q.NID
  WHEN @curCode THEN
   @curRow := @curRow + 1
  ELSE
   @curRow := 1
  AND @curCode := q.NID
  END
 ) AS No
FROM UserInfo q,
(
  SELECT
   @curRow := 1,
   @curCode := ''
 ) rt
WHERE q.NID IN
(
    SELECT NID
    FROM UserInfo
    GROUP BY NID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

after that create a table and insert result to it.

```html
create table CopyTable 
SELECT q.id,q.name,q.password,q.NID,(select count(*) from UserInfo k where k.NID= q.NID) as Count,
(
  CASE q.NID
  WHEN @curCode THEN
   @curRow := @curRow + 1
  ELSE
   @curRow := 1
  AND @curCode := q.NID
  END
 ) AS No
FROM UserInfo q,
(
  SELECT
   @curRow := 1,
   @curCode := ''
 ) rt
WHERE q.NID IN
(
    SELECT NID
    FROM UserInfo
    GROUP BY NID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Finally, delete dublicate rows.No is start 0. Except fist number of each group delete all dublicate rows.

```html
delete from  CopyTable where No!= 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM 
 some_table t1,
  (SELECT relevant_field
  FROM some_table
  GROUP BY relevant_field
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1) t2
WHERE
 t1.relevant_field = t2.relevant_field;
```

Answer (score 1):

sometimes when data grow bigger mysql WHERE IN's could be pretty slow because of query optimization. Try using STRAIGHT_JOIN to tell mysql to execute query as is, e.g.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN table.field FROM table WHERE table.id IN (...)
```

but beware: in most cases mysql optimizer works pretty well, so I would recommend to use it only when you have this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to my case, where I have a table named `tabel_buku_besar`. What I need are

1. Looking for record that have `account_code='101.100'` in `tabel_buku_besar` which have `companyarea='20000'` and also have `IDR` as `currency`
2. I need to get all record from `tabel_buku_besar` which have account_code same as step 1 but have `transaction_number` in step 1 result

while using `select ... from...where....transaction_number in (select transaction_number from ....)`, my query running extremely slow and sometimes causing request time out or make my application not responding...

I try this combination and the result...not bad...

```
`select DATE_FORMAT(L.TANGGAL_INPUT,'%d-%m-%y') AS TANGGAL,
      L.TRANSACTION_NUMBER AS VOUCHER,
      L.ACCOUNT_CODE,
      C.DESCRIPTION,
      L.DEBET,
      L.KREDIT 
 from (select * from tabel_buku_besar A
                where A.COMPANYAREA='$COMPANYAREA'
                      AND A.CURRENCY='$Currency'
                      AND A.ACCOUNT_CODE!='$ACCOUNT'
                      AND (A.TANGGAL_INPUT BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$StartDate','%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$EndDate','%d/%m/%Y'))) L 
INNER JOIN (select * from tabel_buku_besar A
                     where A.COMPANYAREA='$COMPANYAREA'
                           AND A.CURRENCY='$Currency'
                           AND A.ACCOUNT_CODE='$ACCOUNT'
                           AND (A.TANGGAL_INPUT BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$StartDate','%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$EndDate','%d/%m/%Y'))) R ON R.TRANSACTION_NUMBER=L.TRANSACTION_NUMBER AND R.COMPANYAREA=L.COMPANYAREA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN master_account C ON C.ACCOUNT_CODE=L.ACCOUNT_CODE AND C.COMPANYAREA=L.COMPANYAREA 
ORDER BY L.TANGGAL_INPUT,L.TRANSACTION_NUMBER`
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be the most efficient for finding if a value exists, logic can easily be inverted to find if a value doesn't exist (ie IS NULL);

```
SELECT * FROM primary_table st1
LEFT JOIN comparision_table st2 ON (st1.relevant_field = st2.relevant_field)
WHERE st2.primaryKey IS NOT NULL
```

*Replace relevant_field with the name of the value that you want to check exists in your table

*Replace primaryKey with the name of the primary key column on the comparison table.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because your sub-query is executed once for every comparison between `relevant_field` and your `IN` clause's sub-query.  You can avoid that like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table T1 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT relevant_field
    FROM some_table
    GROUP BY relevant_field
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T2 
USING(relevant_field)
```

This creates a derived table (in memory unless it's too large to fit) as T2, then `INNER JOIN`'s it with T1.  The JOIN happens one time, so the query is executed one time.

I find this particularly handy for optimising cases where a pivot is used to associate a bulk data table with a more specific data table and you want to produce counts of the bulk table based on a subset of the more specific one's related rows.  If you can narrow down the bulk rows to <5% then the resulting sparse accesses will generally be faster than a full table scan.

ie you have a Users table (condition), an Orders table (pivot) and LineItems table (bulk) which references counts of Products.  You want the sum of Products grouped by User in `PostCode` '90210'.  In this case the JOIN will be orders of magnitude smaller than when using `WHERE relevant_field IN( SELECT * FROM (...) T2 )`, and therefore much faster, especially if that JOIN is spilling to disk!