# SELECT WHERE IN (subquery) slow

Tags: mysql, performance, select, subquery, where-clause

I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why), but it doesn't work.

My table is like this:

```
   `Index`  uid   dept
...........................
      1    001   dept1
      2    001   dept2
      3    001   dept3
      4    002   dept2
      5    002   dept3
      6    002   dept4
      7    003   dept1
      8    003   dept5
      9    004   dept1
      10   004   dept6
```

I want to retrieve all the rows with a particular `dept`. That is, If I want to retrieve `dept1`, I want to retrieve all rows except uid=002, since there's no `dept1` for uid=002.

The query string is slow even when using index:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE uid IN
(SELECT uid WHERE dept='dept1')
```

My previous version without using WHERE IN is as following:

> Retrieves all the uid with dept=dept1 first.
>   Then use a for-loop for all uid retrieved in the first query.

This method is very fast for a small amount(100) of rows retrieved in the first query. However, it seems that it's not a good solution because it creates a lot of queries(each of them is extremely fast).

Comment: This is similar with this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select a.id from Table1 a
inner join Table1 b on a.uid = b.uid and b.dept = 'dept1';
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05774/4

Comment: [When is `IN (SELECT ...)` performance going to be improved?](http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2008/09/drizzling-mysql.html)

Comment: Good news: [MariaDB 5.3](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/what-is-mariadb-53) is already out as a stable release. And MySQL 5.6 (not stable yet, but soon I think) will have these or similar improvements.

Comment: This query is equivalent to the subquery version. I'm glad that mysql improve the performance in newer version. However, the stable version for debian squeeze is still 5.1.