# Mysql subquery returns incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I know this is a very stupid thing to ask, and believe me I tried everything. This is my last resort.

I am trying to run a subquery. Surprisingly mysql hangs (even though its not a big query).

I am trying to run this query to return me a list of Link_ids

```
    select distinct link_id from join_link_object where obj_id = (select group_concat(obj_id) from xalt_object where module_name like '%intel-compilers/2016.0.047%');

+---------+
| link_id |
+---------+
|  153249 |
+---------+
```

The result returned is not correct. Instead of returning the list of link_id query returns just the first one.

I know using `=` is not a good idea, I tried using `IN` but the prompt just hangs and returns nothing.

Although running subquery separately and then running the main query with its results gives correct results (verified manually).

```
mysql> select group_concat(obj_id) from xalt_object where module_name like '%intel-compilers/2016.0.047%';
+-------------------------------------------+
| group_concat(obj_id)                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 352304,352305,352306,352307,352308,354813 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

then running main query -

```
mysql> select distinct link_id from join_link_object where obj_id in (352304,352305,352306,352307,352308,354813);
+---------+
| link_id |
+---------+
|  153249 |
|  153467 |
|  153996 |
|  154170 |
|  155077 |
|  155099 |
|  155100 |
+---------+
```

I even tried using EXISTS, but these query returns absurd results (around 156995 rows)-

```
select distinct link_id from join_link_object where EXISTS  (select obj_id from xalt_object where module_name like '%intel-compilers/2016.0.047%');
```

Please advice! Thanks

Comment: In the first query you use `where obj_id =` in the penultimate query you use `where obj_id in` try using `in` at the first query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first query you're comparing the `obj_id` with the subquery result, when you should be filtering the obj_id `in` the subquery result, as you did in the test:

```
select distinct link_id 
from join_link_object 
where obj_id in (352304,352305,352306,352307,352308,354813);
```

Here's what it should be:

```
select distinct link_id 
from join_link_object 
where obj_id 
in (select obj_id from xalt_object where module_name like '%intel-compilers/2016.0.047%');
```

To improve performance try this out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT jlo.link_id 
FROM join_link_object AS jlo 
INNER JOIN xalt_object AS xo 
ON (jlo.obj_id = xo.obj_id) 
WHERE xo.module_name LIKE '%intel-compilers/2016.0.047%';
```

Comment: As I said i tried IN but the whole thing just hangs.

Comment: I see, the problem is `group_concat`

Comment: Holy cow! seriously, I think I am in that phase where I can't think straight. Thanks this worked. But the whole query takes like 7.17 secs and this is when the list of obj_id is very small. I was wondering if there is a way I can make is faster.

Comment: use a `joins` @user3802162 check out [this blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/), and [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023117/select-where-in-subquery-slow)

Comment: Thanks a ton Jonathan, appreciate your help although I can't mark this as resolved (low reputation). I will find some way to close it.

Comment: Did it work? how much does it take now? What you mean by low rep jaja?

Comment: Yeah it does. Significantly less from 7.07 secs down to 0.18 secs. I tried to upvote your answer but I can't as it throws me an error (saying my reputation is low)