# Slow MySQL query using sub select and IF conditionals

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm having a little problem and would like some advice.
What I want to do is select everything from tableA where there is an entry in tableB WHERE the entry in tableB is the first entry within the table and that entry is within a specific date range.

So with an start date of 2013-01-01 00:00:00 and an end date of 2013-01-31 23:59:59 I need to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblsites WHERE ID IN(SELECT 
IF(DateRequired >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND DateRequired <= '2013-01-31 23:59:59', SiteID, '' ) AS SiteID FROM `tblmovements` WHERE TicketStatus IN ( 0, 1 ) GROUP BY SiteID) AND LENGTH(SiteName)>0 ORDER BY SiteName ASC
```

Basically it should return me a list of site data where that site has had its first movement within the date range selected.  The DateRequired column is my movement date in tblmovements and tblmovements stores the SiteID as a column.  Ticket status you can ignore its just a flag to say the ticket is active it shouldn't have an outcome on the query.

So my theory was if I select all the tickets within tblmovements where they are active and and group them on the siteid then I could have the sub query only return the site ID if the DateRequired was between my input dates which would then allow me to do a simple SELECT WHERE IN() on the sites tables.  The LENGTH clause is simply because the if returns a zero length on the else clause so rather than filter it out in script I'd like to filter them out on query.

The query runs with no errors but is absolubtly slow as hell (30 minutes + and still running) I can't for the life of me think of a better way of writing it its probably just Friday morning blues but any suggestions to wake me back up would be much appreciated.
A better way of writing it completely would also be fine if you can make sense of my rambling above.

**EDIT:**
Dummy Tables.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tblmovements`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblmovements` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SiteID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `TicketStatus` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DateRequired` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `SiteID` (`SiteID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblmovements`
--

INSERT INTO `tblmovements` (`ID`, `SiteID`, `TicketStatus`, `DateRequired`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2013-01-02 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 1, '2013-01-02 00:00:00'),
(3, 1, 1, '2013-02-02 00:00:00'),
(4, 1, 1, '2013-02-02 00:00:00'),
(5, 1, 1, '2013-02-02 00:00:00'),
(6, 2, 1, '2012-02-02 00:00:00'),
(7, 2, 1, '2012-02-02 00:00:00'),
(8, 2, 1, '2012-01-20 00:00:00'),
(9, 2, 1, '2013-01-02 00:00:00'),
(10, 2, 1, '2013-01-02 00:00:00');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblsites`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblsites` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SiteName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblsites`
--

INSERT INTO `tblsites` (`ID`, `SiteName`) VALUES
(1, 'Site 1'),
(2, 'Site 2');
```

**EDIT 2:**

OK on steves suggestion I've changed the query to this

```
SELECT tblmovements.SiteID, tblsites.SiteName FROM tblmovements
INNER JOIN tblsites
 ON tblmovements.SiteID = tblsites.ID
WHERE (tblmovements.TicketStatus = 0 OR tblmovements.TicketStatus = 1)
AND tblmovements.DateRequired>='2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND tblmovements.DateRequired<='2013-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY tblmovements.SiteID
```

Which is now semi-working.  The problem I have now though is that this is only selecting if there is a ticket between that date range.  What I now need to do is only return the result set IF the entry in the tblmovements is the first occurance of that site ID within that table.
If you go back to the primary query you'll notice there's an IF on the sub select.

**EDIT 3**

Right I think I've cracked it based off Steves input and sudden flash of non-Friday morning moron.

```
SELECT tblmovements.SiteID, tblsites.SiteName FROM tblmovements
INNER JOIN tblsites
 ON tblmovements.SiteID = tblsites.ID
WHERE (tblmovements.TicketStatus = 0 OR tblmovements.TicketStatus = 1)
AND tblmovements.DateRequired>='2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND tblmovements.DateRequired<='2013-01-31 23:59:59'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblmovements t3 WHERE t3.DateRequired<'2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND t3.SiteID=tblmovements.SiteID)<=0
GROUP BY tblmovements.SiteID
```

Added an additional conditional to just give me a count of tickets before the start date so in theory if it returns a result set where there's tickets between my required dates and there's no tickets before the start date then all the siteid's returned should be the ones I require.

Testing so far is returning the data sets I am expecting which is good and its noticably quicker **Query Execution Time 0.5711 sec** bonus.

Comment: [rambling] should be added to your tags. Consider providing DDLs (CREATE and INSERT statements) together with a desired result set - ideally in the form of an SQLFIDDLE.

Comment: I cannot unfortunately provide the full tables for stupid retarded reasons but still I'm limited by them I've included the important fields though above.  I've been debugging it a little and the subselect works fine (although the as casting and the length clause appear to be ignored so I end up with a load of blank rows) its the select IN() on the primary thats slowing it down and I can't for the life of me think of a better way of doing it. But for reference IN() with a 120k million input array is slow.

Comment: IN is slow - but EXISTS might be faster - although I don't think I've ever tried manipulating anything like 120 billion rows with MySQL!

Comment: I didn't think of EXISTS I shall give that a shot see what it returns.  I didn't mean 120k million I meant 120 million still a large number though.

Comment: Tried exists but the result set returned isn't even slightly close to what it should be and because I can't do an exists ID  = SiteID as the select list is ignored it becomes a too broad match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - SELECT WHERE field IN (subquery) - Extremely slow why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a join rather than a sub query and an IN list?

```
SELECT t1.SiteID, t2.* FROM tblmovements t1
WHERE (TicketStatus = 0 OR TicketStatus = 1)
AND t1.DateRequired BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY t1.SiteID)
INNER JOIN tblsites t2
 ON t1.SiteID = t2.ID
```

**Edit 1 - in reply to comments:**

What I've done here is move your IF evaluation into a WHERE condition statement.

The original query would be selecting a large range of rows and then evaluating them to writing either their SiteID or ''.  Why select a large range when you can narrow that down with a where condition?

Comment: I don't index on date required but I also can't use a where daterequired BETWEEN because there could be tickets preceeding the date range. So if I'm selecting for a january date range but there are also tickets in december I don't want that SiteID to turn up as I only want the SiteID to be returned if the very first entry in the movements table is between the date range.  I could achieve what I want with multiple separate queries and manipulating the result sets in script but if possible I'd like to do it all in one query as the DB servers are considerably more powerful than the web front ends

Comment: @Dave I've made an edit to the answer. Unfortunately there is too much information missing in your question and your explanation to be more specific.

Comment: What additional information do you require I'll provide what I can I am just horrible at explaining things though I have it in my head what I want to do but between the brain and fingers they're having a disagreement.

Comment: between isn't the same as >= and <= its the same as > < it doesn't include the primary selection date but I get the rest of it I'm going to give it a spin now see what happens.

Comment: I've updated the initial question with the new trial the problem is now its including sites in the result set that have movements before the dates.  What I need is where the ticket returned in the between dates is the FIRST occurance of the site ID within the tickets.  As attempted by my IF in the very first query.