# SQL statement for join but not in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables: `customer` and `mailing` :

```
+==========+  +=============+
| customer |  | mailing     |
+==========+  +=============+
| id       |  | id          |
+----------+  +-------------+
| name     |  | customer_id |
+----------+  +-------------+
              | mailing_id  |
              +-------------+
```

Every time I send a mailing to a customer, I add a row in the mailings table with that mailing id. One mailing can be sent to multiple customers.

I want to have a sql call that returns all customers that have not yet received a certain mailing. How to ?

I am using mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from customer where id not in (
    select customer_id from mailing where mailing_id = @mailing_id
)
```

Comment: if it is MySQL, `IN ()` does not work properly when containing a subquery and can run for hours even on very small tables

Comment: @DanFromGermany Really? According to this link it compares quite well to `NOT EXISTS` http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Why do you have the condition in the subquery? It's not needed, is it?

Comment: @joe776 that post is from 2009, compare with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why "_Never use IN with a subquery; this is notoriously slow.
Only ever use IN with a fixed list of values._"

Comment: @DanFromGermany IMHO, evaluating a query plan beats "I never use X because it's notoriously slow". There is no evidence in the answer as to why it should be like that. Of course, it always depends on the actual data inside your DB, indexes, etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM customers c
JOIN mailings m
ON c.id = m.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id
    FROM mailings i
    WHERE i.id = c.id
    GROUP BY i.id
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is 100% correct now, if OP needs any further help, pls setup an sqlfiddle

Comment: The join between `customer` and `mailing` requires that there already is a mailing for the customer. Furthermore, the subquery always returns a result if there is any mailing for a customer, so if there is any mailing at all you won't get results.

Comment: right, updated :) I'm still not sure about the `IN ()`, we had a lot of problems with subqueries in `IN ()` and I often read that they don't work, even with percona or Mariadb

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
Select c.ID, c.Name
From Customers C
left Join mailing m On c.id = m.customer_id
where m.customer_id is null
```

Comment: And this one is the fastest one, unless you have to use distinct!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called an `ANTI JOIN`. Usually there are three different ways for formulating it in SQL: A `NOT IN` condition with a subquery, a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery, or a `LEFT JOIN` with a `NOT NULL` condition.
So for your query the possibilities are:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE id NOT IN
    ( SELECT customer_id
     FROM mailing)
```

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT customer_id
     FROM mailing m
     WHERE m.customer_id = c.id)
```

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN mailing m ON c.id = m.customer_id
WHERE m.customer_id IS NULL
```

[This blog post](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) compares the different possibilities with MySQL 5.1. According to it, `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT IN` are faster than `NOT EXISTS`.
However, you should try for yourself which one is the fastest. That always depends on your data, indexes, ...