# MySQL where in executes slow if sub query is used, where as using list executes fast

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

the following executes fast:

> delete from text_blocks
>   where text_id in (
>   7684,
>   7683,
>   7682,
>   ...);

Note, the above list of values is short e.g. 130 retrieved from a separate query.  Table text_blocks has ~ 7,000 rows.

The following executes really slow:

> delete from text_blocks
>   where text_id in (select a_text_id from someTable
>   where name like "%_SomeSuffix");

The subquery in example 2 is the same as used to get the list of 130 in example 1.  Neither text_id or a_text_id are indexed.

Any ideas why it is super slow, and or hanging?

Comment: `like "%_SomeSuffix"` <--- this

Comment: @zerkms: But why wouldn't MySql just cache the result, and use the cached results for the `in` clause in the top-level query?  Seems like it's running the subquery for every row returned in the top-level query.

Comment: seems like it is running the subquery for every row, but why?  The sub query runs fast by itself with the wildcard (i.e. executed separately 1 time).  The whole idea is that I don't want to run the sub query manually to create the list (and then have to edit and paste it ugh).  The _SomeSuffix is so that I can easily identify the rows I've recently added and want to delete.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: because mysql isn't (wasn't?) good in optimizing nested queries. The decent DBMS (oracle, postgresql, sql server) would optimize the given query the same way as `INNER JOIN` or `EXISTS` one.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is notorious for having very poor performance for queries/subqueries like

```
select ...from ... where ... in (select ....);
```

Try using `EXISTS` instead of `IN` and you should see a dramatic improvement.  See

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why
```

for more info

Comment: A temporary table helped considerably, but I'd still say it is too slow so I'll look at what you suggest.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table)