# How many times const subquery in select is executed?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have query:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT `name` from `config` WHERE id = 1) AS 'config' FROM customers
```

How many times is the subquery executed? Does MySql cache this subquery constant or does it execute it for every row?

Comment: You could also have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777052/mysql-where-in-executes-slow-if-sub-query-is-used-where-as-using-list-executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple question here is your simple answer:

The subquery is only executed once, and the result is indeed held in a cache. It does NOT get executed for each row. That is, of course, unless you add a modifier such as `SQL_NO_CACHE` to it.