# Select the fields are duplicated in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that I have the below `customer_offer` table.

My question is:

> How to select all the rows where the ***key(s)*** are duplicated in that table?

```
+---------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| link_id | customer_id | partner_id | offer_id | key    | date_updated        |
+---------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------------+
|       1 |          99 |         11 |       14 | mmmmmq | 2011-09-21 12:40:46 |
|       2 |         100 |         11 |       14 | qmmmmq | 2011-09-21 12:40:46 |
|       3 |         101 |         11 |       14 | 8mmmmq | 2011-09-21 12:40:46 |
|       4 |          99 |         11 |       14 | Dmmmmq | 2011-09-21 12:59:28 |
|       5 |         100 |         11 |       14 | Nmmmmq | 2011-09-21 12:59:28 |
+---------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

### UPDATE:

Thanks so much for all your answer. There are many answers are good. Now I got the solution to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from customer_offer 
where key in 
(select key from customer_offer group by key having count(*) > 1)
```

**Update:**
As mentioned from @Scorpi0, if with a big table, it is better to use join. And from mysql6.0 the new optimizer will convert this kind of subqueries into joins.

Comment: Warning with big table and many duplicate, this query could not be optimal

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/sql-join-vs-subquery

Comment: @Scorpi0: Thanks you. Now, my knowledge is more better.

Answer (score 1):

`Self join`

```
SELECT * FROM customer_offer c1 inner join customer_offer c2
on c1.key = c2.key
```

or `group by` the field then take when `count > 1`

```
SELECT COUNT(key),link_id FROM customer_offer c1
group by key, link_id
having COUNT(Key) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.* 
FROM customer_offer c1 
    INNER JOIN customer_offer c2
        ON c1.key = c2.key
        AND c1.link_id != c2.link_id
```

Assuming `link_id` is a primary key.

Comment: +2: Thanks you so much for your confirm to the answer which is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many threads on the mysql website which explains how to do this. This link will explain how to do this using mysql: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,180556,180567#msg-180567

As a brief example the code below is from the link with a slight modification which better suits your example.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
GROUP BY key
HAVING COUNT(key)>1;
```

You can also use a joing which is my prefered method, as this removes the slower count method:

```
SELECT * 
FROM this_table t 
inner join this_table t1 on t.key = t1.key
```

Comment: This will not select all rows where `key` is duplicated. It will select a *singe* row for each duplicated key.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to do the count check, and the main query to select the rows. The count check query is simply:

```
SELECT `link_id` FROM `customer_offer` GROUP BY `key` HAVING COUNT(`key`) > 1
```

Then the outer query will use this by joining into it:

```
SELECT customer_offer.* FROM customer_offer
INNER JOIN (SELECT `link_id` FROM `customer_offer` GROUP BY `key` HAVING COUNT(`key`) > 1) AS count_check
ON customer_offer.link_id = count_check.link_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT link_id, key, count(key) as Occurrences 
FROM table 
GROUP BY key
HAVING COUNT(key)>1;
```