# Which is better Sub-Query or JOIN in SQl query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Can any one suggest which one is better in this case:

## 1:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN1, 
        (SELECT 
            COLUMN2 
        FROM
            TABLE2
        WHERE 
            <some condition>) AS COLUMN2
FROM TABLE 1
```

## 2:

```
SELECT
    T1.COLUMN1,
    T2.COLUMN2
FROM
    TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN 
    TABLE2 T2 ON <some condition>
```

Comment: Did you try searching here? It looks like the question in this thread is identical to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/sql-join-vs-subquery

Comment: The better query is the one that returns the desired result. I guess that there can be some situations where the two queries are interchangeable but certainly not always. The sub query version will fail if you get more than one row back from the sub query for a given condition.

Comment: The better query is the one that returns the desired results in lesser time.

Comment: The better query is the one that returns the desired results using fewer database resources and fast enough to meet your application's requirements. That said, Smruti is asking whether it is better to solve a given problem with a subquery or a join. The example isn't great (or even really necessary), but the question is clear enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subqueries vs joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the analysis tools to optimize your query:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3925251/Using-MySQLs-Analysis-Tools-to-Improve-Query-Performance.htm

Answer (score 4):

There are several axis of "better"...

- Better performance
- Better readability
- Better maintainability
- Better flexibility
  ....

  So,

  1. Test and find out (examine plans they may be identical)
  2. In the eye of the beholder, where the queries are equvalent I prefer joins
  3. Depends on your staff
  4. Doesn't seem applicable in this case
     ...

Better is frequently just a trade off...

Answer (score 3):

Use JOIN.

[Subqueries vs joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins)

Answer (score 2):

> Which is better?

**It is not the problem which is better, because they are complete different query.**

Your first query will be error if your sub query return more than 1 row.