# multiple tag search query not working

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a query to search data by multiple tags, I got this idea from this question [Multiple tags search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762333/multiple-tags-search-query/8762620#8762620). I have 3 table such as books(id, title....). tags(id,name), books_tag(id,book_id,tag_id). So I use my query to select the books by tags but it is not giving any results.

Books Table

```
id : title
 1 : maths
 2 : science
 3 : HP
```

Tag Table

```
id : name
 1 : a
 2 : b
 3 : c
```

Boook_tag Table

```
id : book_id : tag_id
 1 :    1    :   2
 2 :    1    :   3 
 3 :    2    :   1
 4 :    3    :   1
 5 :    3    :   2
```

So if I search book tag c, the result should be book_id 1 (maths) OR search by c and a, the result should be book_id 1,2,3 (maths, science, HP)

This is my query

```
SELECT books_tag.book_id, books_pre.title
FROM books_tag
JOIN books_pre ON books_tag.book_id = books_pre.id
JOIN tags ON books_tag.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.name IN ('a', 'd')
GROUP BY books_tag.book_id
HAVING COUNT(books_tag.tag_id) = 2
```

Comment: Its hard to say something without viewing your data, Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you are trying is for `AND` criteria like get those books which have tag a AND tag d, As per your question you don't need that criteria, just remove the group by and having clause and you will be fine

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*
FROM books_pre b
JOIN books_tag bt ON bt.book_id = b.id
JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.name IN ('a', 'b')
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3dc7d6/6)

Comment: but it is repeating the books again if search by a, b which should not be,

Comment: can u please explain to me why u added a letter after table name, what is the meaning of this b.*, I'm kind of newbie to mysql, and thank for your answer,

Comment: @Looper its just an alias (short name)  for table to use in query , like you could also write as books.* but keeping it shorter i use aliases, Aliases are good  when you have same column name in 2 tables like you can use alias.column to identify each

Answer (score 0):

You should use count(distinct books_tag.tag_id)

```
SELECT books_tag.book_id, books_pre.title
FROM books_tag
JOIN books_pre ON books_tag.book_id = books_pre.id
JOIN tags ON books_tag.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.name IN ('a', 'd')
GROUP BY books_tag.book_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct books_tag.tag_id) = 2
```

Comment: I used it but not giving any results

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

Try this short query:

Sample data:

```
create table Books(id int, title varchar(10));
insert into Books values
(1, 'maths'),
(2, 'science'),
(3, 'HP');
create table Tag(id int, name char(1));
insert into Tag values                            
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(3, 'c');
create table Book_tag(id int, book_id int, tag_id int);
insert into Book_tag values
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 2, 1),
(4, 3, 1),
(5, 3, 2);
```

T-SQL:

```
select distinct book_id from Book_tag bt
where exists(select 1 from Tag
             where id = bt.tag_id
                   and name in ('c', 'a'));
```

in part `name in (...)` you specify tags you want to search for.