# unable to find desired result in search filter query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am trying from last 2 days to get desired result in query but unable to do that. Basically I am making query for a restaurant website "tag based" search filter to search in the favorite dishes.

There are a separate table for tags in which so many tags are saved against meal_id, restaurant_id . Many to many relationship of restaurants-> tags and meals-> tags..

The more tags users enter the less results should come.

Please have a look at the query

```
SELECT
   ep_tag.tag_en as tag_meal,
   ep_tag2.tag_en as tag_restaurant,
   `ep_meal`.id as id_meal,
   `ep_meal`.name as name_plat,
   `ep_meal`.`id_budget`,
   `ep_meal_favorite`.date,
   `ep_restaurant`.id as `id_restaurant`,
   `ep_restaurant`.* 
from
   `ep_meal` 
   inner join
      `ep_meal_favorite` 
      on `ep_meal_favorite`.`id_meal` = `ep_meal`.id 
   inner join
      `ep_restaurant` 
      on `ep_meal_favorite`.`id_restaurant` = `ep_restaurant`.`id` 
   inner JOIN
      ep_tag 
      ON ep_meal_favorite.id_meal = ep_tag.id_meal 
   inner JOIN
      ep_tag as ep_tag2 
      ON ep_meal_favorite.id_restaurant = ep_tag2.id_restaurant 
where
   ep_meal_favorite.id_epicurean = 82 
   and `ep_restaurant`.id = 14 
   and `ep_meal`.id = 92 
   AND 
   (
      ep_tag.tag_en LIKE '%tuna%' 
      OR ep_tag2.tag_en LIKE'%tuna%'
   )
   AND 
   (
      ep_tag.tag_en LIKE '%karaoke%' 
      OR ep_tag2.tag_en LIKE'%karaoke%'
   )
```

[image]

above posted picture is current result,the problem is query return records where tag_meal is **"tuna"** and tag_restaurant is **"karaoke"** but it returns empty when one is matched but other one does not.

I Want the query to return results when even one condition matched let suppose i write 2 tags for **"meal"** and no tag for **"restaurant"** and vice versa, at the same time i want the query to use AND because I want to reduce the number of results.

Please help me in this regard.Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would make things easier.

Comment: I have provided all the things already.

Comment: That image with the tiny text, is it sample table data or the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh it is current result

Comment: @jarlh check now, it is more readable

Comment: If you want all the coincidences just use or. Anyways, that query is not the one that gets the result at the img. The condition: AND 
   (
      ep_tag.tag_en LIKE '%cheese%' 
      OR ep_tag2.tag_en LIKE'%cheese%'
   ) is not fulfilled.

Comment: @dev . . . I don't know what the question is.  You have mentioned an app, described n-m relationships, and shown an inscrutable query.  I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have correct it.

Comment: @Elanochecer please check now. I have corrected.

Comment: Try [Multiple tags search query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8762333) (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: @Solarflare the refrence you have provided is using one column while i am using two columns.

Answer (score 0):

As i commented the way to obtain all the rows that match one or another record is to OR them.

```
SELECT
   ep_tag.tag_en as tag_meal,
   ep_tag2.tag_en as tag_restaurant,
   `ep_meal`.id as id_meal,
   `ep_meal`.name as name_plat,
   `ep_meal`.`id_budget`,
   `ep_meal_favorite`.date,
   `ep_restaurant`.id as `id_restaurant`,
   `ep_restaurant`.* 
from
   `ep_meal` 
   inner join
      `ep_meal_favorite` 
      on `ep_meal_favorite`.`id_meal` = `ep_meal`.id 
   inner join
      `ep_restaurant` 
      on `ep_meal_favorite`.`id_restaurant` = `ep_restaurant`.`id` 
   inner JOIN
      ep_tag 
      ON ep_meal_favorite.id_meal = ep_tag.id_meal 
   inner JOIN
      ep_tag as ep_tag2 
      ON ep_meal_favorite.id_restaurant = ep_tag2.id_restaurant 
where
   ep_meal_favorite.id_epicurean = 82 
   and `ep_restaurant`.id = 14 
   and `ep_meal`.id = 92 
   AND 
   (
      ep_tag.tag_en LIKE '%tuna%' 
      OR ep_tag2.tag_en LIKE'%tuna%'
      OR ep_tag.tag_en LIKE '%karaoke%' 
      OR ep_tag2.tag_en LIKE'%karaoke%'
   )
```

This is not so efficient tho. You can build a regex to optimize.