# I need to get posts data from 3 taxonomies (profile-category, county,Sector)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Below query is working with one taxonomy

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM bb_posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN bb_term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id) 
INNER JOIN bb_term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id) 
INNER JOIN bb_terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id) 
WHERE p.post_type IN ('post', 'profile') 
AND p.post_status = 'publish' 
AND x.taxonomy = 'profile-category' 
AND t.term_id = '577' 
AND x.taxonomy = 'county' 
AND t.term_id = '804' 
AND x.taxonomy = 'Sector' 
AND t.term_id = '830' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

How to get posts data from 3 taxonomies?

Comment: Hope this will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762333/multiple-tags-search-query

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution

SELECT * FROM bb_posts
                LEFT JOIN bb_term_relationships ON (bb_posts.ID = bb_term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN bb_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (bb_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) 
                LEFT JOIN bb_term_relationships AS tt2 ON (bb_posts.ID = tt2.object_id)
                INNER JOIN bb_postmeta ON ( bb_posts.ID = bb_postmeta.post_id )
                WHERE 1=1
                AND ( 
                  bb_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (689) 
                  AND 
                  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (798) 
                  AND 
                  tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (828)
                ) AND ( 
                  ( bb_postmeta.meta_key = 'sector' AND bb_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Wheelchair%' )
                ) AND
                bb_posts.post_type IN ('allusers', 'profile') 
                AND (bb_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                OR bb_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' 
                OR bb_posts.post_author = 1 AND bb_posts.post_status = 'private')
                GROUP BY bb_posts.ID 
                ORDER BY bb_posts.ID
                DESC LIMIT 0, 12