# Changing query to add results from secondary table

Tags: php, mysql

The query below works well.  Now I would like to add another table called **addresses**, which contains the same `submissionid` and `zip` variables below.  I would like to pull all the `submissionid` variables from **addresses** where `zip = '$zip'`, then use these results to look up the corresponding `title` rows from the **submission** table in the query below.

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
             FROM submission 
            WHERE zip = '$zip'
         ORDER BY points DESC, title ASC              
     LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can acheve this using subquery

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
         FROM submission 
        WHERE submissionid IN(
              SELECT submissionid 
              FROM addreses
              WHERE zip = '$zip')
     ORDER BY points DESC, title ASC              
 LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Reference: [IN Subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Or with JOIN

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.title, s.points, s.submissionid
         FROM submission s 
         INNER JOIN addresses ad
         on ad.submissionid = s.submissionid
         WHERE ad.zip = '$zip'
     ORDER BY s.points DESC, s.title ASC              
 LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Reference: [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

And as @AdrianCornish mentioned in comment INNER join is faster than subquery. So you should better go for the second option with JOIN.

A related thread on SO [Subqueries vs joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins)

Comment: INNER JOIN is usually much better optimized in my experience with mysql. eg I wrote a query yesterday very similar - 36seconds for the WHERE/IN and 0.06 seconds for the INNER JOIN against a tmp table

Comment: @Joy I thought this worked, but it actually omits results from **submission**

Comment: @John Depending on what you want, you may need a different join like `left` or `right`. But thats hard to say without having a look at your data, can you please elaborate how is it omitting data?