# Mysql to select rows group by with order by another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the rows from a table by 'group by' and ignoring the first row got by sorting the data by date. The sorting should be done by a date field, to ignore the newest entry and returning the old ones for the group.

The table looks like

```
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | updated on | group_name  | list_name |
+----+------------+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 2013-04-03 | g1          | l1        |
| 2  | 2013-03-21 | g2          | l1        |
| 3  | 2013-02-26 | g2          | l1        |
| 4  | 2013-02-21 | g1          | l1        |
| 5  | 2013-02-20 | g1          | l1        |
| 6  | 2013-01-09 | g2          | l2        |
| 7  | 2013-01-10 | g2          | l2        |
| 8  | 2012-12-11 | g1          | l1        |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec99/1

So, basically, I just want to return ids (3,4,5,6,8) as those are the oldest in the group_name and list_name. Ignoring the latest entry and returning the old ones by grouping it based on group_name and list_name

I am not able to write sql for this problem. I know order by will not work with group by. Please help me in figuring out a solution.

Thanks

And also, is there a way to do this without using subqueries?

Comment: Please, take the time to put together a coherent request for help. I have absolutely no idea what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Can you please explain it further ? What do you mean by " based on group_name and list_name" ? Do you want to fetch a single(old) row from each group. ?

Comment: @Vivek, yes, but I need all the old entries made for group_name ignoring the id 1 for group_name g1, as thats the newest entry made

Comment: Please use SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @user2436575 Why not '7'?

Comment: @Strawberry because 7 is the newest in the group (g2,l2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following to get only the rows that are the minimum date for a specific row:

```
select a.ID, a.updated_on, a.group_name, list_name
from data a 
where
a.updated_on < 
(
select max(updated_on)
from data 
group by group_name having group_name = a.group_name
);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00d43/10

### Update (based on your reqs)

```
select a.ID, a.updated_on, a.group_name, list_name
from data a 
where
a.updated_on < 
(
select max(updated_on)
from data 
group by group_name, list_name having group_name = a.group_name
  and list_name = a.list_name
);
```

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec99/3

### Update (To not use Correlated Subquery but Simple subquery)

Decided correlated subquery is too slow based on: [Subqueries vs joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins)

So I changed to joining with a aliased temporary table based on nested query.

```
select a.ID, a.updated_on, a.group_name, a.list_name
from data a,
(
select group_name, list_name , max(updated_on) as MAX_DATE
from data 
group by group_name, list_name 
) as MAXDATE   
where
a.list_name = MAXDATE.list_name AND
a.group_name = MAXDATE.group_name AND
a.updated_on < MAXDATE.MAX_DATE
;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5df64/8

Comment: But I need all the entries of the group except the newest one

Comment: Oh ok...just a small edit is needed to play with the max instead :) There you go... smaller than the max aka newest entry...

Comment: Updated sqlfiddle with new data. Thanks for your answer. But its not what i expected. the return set should be (3,4,5,6,8). As id-7 is the newest in the group g2 & l2

Comment: @user2436575 give me your link for the SQL Fiddle... I thought you wanted to ignore the newest entry PER group_name... you want to ignore the newest entry overall?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec99/1 forgot to post link. I want to ignore the newest entry made for both group_name and list_name. should return only (3,4,5,6,8) in this case

Comment: See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec99/3 . Please update your question to reflect your reqs better.

Comment: Ok thanks. is there a way to do this without using sub queries? because this table has 10 million records

Comment: @user2436575, could you run both queries on your data and post the results?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following query (yes, it has a nested join, but maybe it helps).

```
SELECT ID FROM 
(select d1.ID FROM data d1 LEFT JOIN 
data d2 ON (d1.group_name = d2.group_name AND d1.list_name=d2.list_name AND 
d1.updated_on > d2.updated_on) WHERE d2.ID IS NULL) data_tmp;
```

**CORRECTION:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM 
(select d1.* FROM data d1 LEFT JOIN 
data d2 ON (d1.group_name = d2.group_name AND d1.list_name=d2.list_name AND 
d1.updated_on < d2.updated_on) WHERE d2.ID IS NOT NULL) date_tmp;
```

Comment: Did you check what results it returns? According to: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec99/10 : {3,6,8}

Comment: I ran your query over 10,000 elements... there is a performance issue related to the unrary join.. 10,000 X 10,000 = 100,000,000 rows before where filter... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.id 
  FROM data x 
  JOIN data y 
    ON y.group_name = x.group_name 
   AND y.list_name = x.list_name 
   AND y.updated_on < x.updated_on;
```