# How to use JOINS instead of sub query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b ON (table_b.id = table_a.id) 
WHERE table_b.created BETWEEN ? AND ? 
      AND table_b.manager IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT (b.id) 
        FROM table_b a 
          INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.manager = b.id 
            AND b.user_level > 0
            AND b.id != 1
      )
```

How can I remove the sub query and use JOINS instead in the above query

Thanks

Comment: please show us your table's structure and example data, and an example of the output you want.

Comment: A join is not necessary a replacement for a sub-query using `IN` - the results may be different (depending on your data model and data)

Comment: What is ur table structure and What you want to accomplish

Comment: make a sqlfiddle maybe? http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.5 (and lower version)'s optimizer produces a [`DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins) for `IN (SELECT ...)` which means every matching row is found, `IN(SELECT ...)` is evaluated that makes select slow.

Simple optimization of your query is make inline view as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON (table_b.id = table_a.id) 
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT b.id AS id
            FROM table_b a 
              INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.manager = b.id 
                AND b.user_level > 0
                AND b.id != 1
    ) x ON table_b.manager = x.id
WHERE table_b.created BETWEEN ? AND ? 
  AND x.id IS NOT NULL;
```

I think avobe query would produce as same as your own.

Last, `DISTINCT` is not a function. please use `SELECT DISTINCT b.id` rather `SELECT DISTINCT (b.id)`