# Add columns when using IN in mysql for the result

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my table for artists -

```
id  name    sex
1   harsh   male
2   geet    female
```

Following is my table for events -

```
id  artist_id  created_by
2   2          16
2   2          17
```

Following is my query -

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE artist_id IN (SELECT id FROM `artists` WHERE name LIKE '%$search_term%')
```

But apart from events data I need to get artist name in the result as well, please let me know what I need to change in my query as I tried `*, artists.name` it wont worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subqueries vs joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT e.*
FROM `artists` AS a
JOIN `events` AS e ON e.artist_id = a.id
WHERE a.name LIKE '%$search_term%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select from two tables simultaneously. Use the [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for that

```
SELECT artists.name, events.*
FROM artists
INNER JOIN events
    ON artist.id = artist_id
WHERE
    name LIKE '%search_term%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `join` instead of an `IN`

```
SELECT 
  e.*, 
  artists.name
FROM 
  `events` e
  inner join `artists` a  on e.artist_id = a.id
WHERE 
  name LIKE '%$search_term%'
```