# Insert into table using join to resolve a single element

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to insert into a table while avoiding a secondary query to lookup an id of a product which is contained in another table.

My insert query:

```
INSERT INTO prod_addfeatures (ProductID, ProdFeature, ProdFeatureTitle) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

ProductID is a `Long Integer`, the other two are simple strings.

At this point in the program, I only have the string representation of the ProductID (the sku, ex: TB100).

To get the numerical id of the sku, I would do something like:

```
SELECT products.catalogid FROM products WHERE id = ?;
```

(`id` is not a PK, rather `catalogid` is... this is a vendor table and cannot be changed).

I'm trying to avoid doing the SELECT before running the INSERT in order to avoid the extra network round-trip (remote database), however I can really only seem to dig up examples of selecting into the table, not quite what I'm after.

For clarity:

Two of the Three values being inserted must be supplied at runtime and do not exist in any other table. One of the Three values being inserted must be looked-up at runtime as it resides in another table.

```
ProductID        <-- Must be selected or joined from the products table
ProdFeature      <-- Supplied at runtime
ProdFeatureTitle <-- Supplied at runtime
```

So I"m trying to get something like:

```
INSERT INTO prod_addfeatures (ProductID, ProdFeature, ProdFeatureTitle) 
    VALUES ((SELECT products.catalogid FROM products WHERE products.id = ?), ?, ?);
```

But I don't believe that is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what value you have that can be used to get the ProductID from the product table.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have `products.id` which is, say, "TB100". The value needed is `products.catalogid` which is, say, "123456".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO prod_addfeatures (ProductID, ProdFeature, ProdFeatureTitle) 
SELECT CatalogId, @ProdFeature, @ProdFeatureTitle
FROM Products
WHERE Id = @ProductId
```

Assuming that the three parameters are the values you are passing from your app.

There is no need for a join, since there is only one table containing data needed for your insert.   The other values come from parameters rather than a table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a sub-select, e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... )
SELECT expression1, expression2, ...
FROM source_table
WHERE conditions;
```

This example from from http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/insert.php

Comment: I don't know how this would work, since I must supply two of the three values at runtime (they do not exist anywhere), the third value must come from another table from some sort of lookup or join.

Comment: In your example this would look like


`INSERT INTO prod_addfeatures (ProductID, ProdFeature, ProdFeatureTitle) VALUES ((SELECT products.catalogid FROM products WHERE id = ?), 'val2', val3')`

Comment: right, that's what I am trying now. It works, but I've always heard doing subqueries are expensive and to join when possible.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question to mean that you were running a second, entirely separate query.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins) implies that the cost of a subquery is greater than a join if you're selecting a lot of rows, but I doubt it would make a big difference in this circumstance.