# countif type function in SQL where total count could be retrieved in other column

Tags: sql, countif

I have 36 columns in a table but one of the columns have data multiple times like below

```
ID       Name       Ref
abcd    john doe    123
1234    martina     100
123x    brittany    123
ab12    joe         101
```

and i want results like

```
ID      Name        Ref cnt
abcd    john doe    123 2
1234    martina     100 1
123x    brittany    123 2
ab12    joe         101 1
```

as 123 has appeared twice i want it to show 2 in cnt column and so on

Comment: What database (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle etc..) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID, Name, Ref, (select count(ID) from [table] where Ref = A.Ref)
from [table] A
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned in comments below, this approach may not be the most efficient in all cases, but should be sufficient on reasonably small tables.

In my testing:

- a table of 5,460 records and 976 distinct 'Ref' values returned in less than 1 second.
- a table of 600,831 records and 8,335 distinct 'Ref' values returned in 6 seconds.
- a table of 845,218 records and 15,147 distinct 'Ref' values returned in 13 seconds.

Comment: Take a look to this article about how to [optimizing correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery#Optimizing_correlated_subqueries)

Comment: @danihp  Interesting.  Will keep it in mind if I find performance an issue, but not sure it warranted a downvote?  Original Post never hinted at the size of the table.  FWIW I got a complete resultset in less than 1 second on a table of 5,460 records and 976 distinct 'Ref'-equivalent values, and 6 seconds for a table of 600,831 records with 8,335 distinct 'Ref'-equivalent values.

Comment: Interesting. Technically I can't remove downvote unless you edit your answer. Perhaps you can include this numbers vs numbers for non correlated query in your answer.

Comment: Also may be a good idea to post execution plan: http://stackoverflow.com/a/141310

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually while i was doing countif with excel it was taking 3-4 hrs that is why i brought this problem here

Answer (score 0):

You should provide SQL brand to know capabilities:

1) If your DB supports [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
Select
   *,
   count(*) over ( partition by ref ) as cnt 
from your_table
```

2) If not:

```
Select
   T.*, G.cnt
from
  ( select * from your_table ) T inner join
  ( select count(*) as cnt from your_table group by ref ) G
  on T.ref = G.ref
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT` with `OVER`in following:

**QUERY**

```
select ID, 
       Name, 
       ref,
       count(ref) over (partition by ref) cnt
from #t t
```

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #t
(
ID NVARCHAR(400),
Name NVARCHAR(400),
Ref INT
)

insert into #t values    
('abcd','john doe',    123),
('1234','martina',     100),
('123x','brittany',    123),
('ab12','joe',         101)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response

Comment: Hey how can i accept it as correct ans? can u olz guide as m unable to find any option like this and this was my first question