# Select IN from multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

So I have a table, lets call it MAIN table, it has the following example columns

```
Name,
Code_1,
Code_2,
Code_3,
Code_4,
Code_5
```

(in my real example there's 25 Code columns)

I have a set of 300 codes that I inserted into a temporary table, what would be the best way to get the rows from the MAIN table where it matches a code from the temporary table?

Here's what I have so far that works, but it seems extremely inefficient

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN WHERE (CODE_1 IN (SELECT CODE FROM TMP_TABLE) 
OR CODE_2 IN(SELECT CODE FROM TMP_TABLE) 
OR CODE_3 IN (SELECT CODE FROM TMP_TABLE)
OR CODE_4 IN (SELECT CODE FROM TMP_TABLE)
OR CODE_5 IN (SELECT CODE FROM TMP_TABLE))
```

Comment: 25 code columns sounds like a bad datamodel. It is not necessarily so, but it seems so. Usually you'd rather have a main table with a name and some ID plus a child table with one record per main ID and code. With such a data model the query would be very simple to write.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I agree, that's pretty bad. At least it's not a single text column with comma-separated codes, so I'd say it's an improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the data model, long story short due to the way that data flows through our systems it does somewhat make sense as we aren't trying to break the data down at that point in the system.

Comment: Then I'd use dasblinkenlight's query. Seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM MAIN m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM TMP_TABLE t
    WHERE t.CODE = m.CODE_1 OR t.CODE = m.CODE_2 OR ...
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this had better performance than the OP's version.

Comment: . . You misunderstood.   I think this would have better performance because Oracle implements skip-scan index searches.

Answer (score 2):

A join would be faster

```
SELECT * FROM MAIN 
inner join TMP_TABLE
on main.code_1 = tmp_table.code 
    or main.code_2 = tmp_table.code 
    or main.code_3 = tmp_table.code
    or main.code_4 = tmp_table.code
    or main.code_5 = tmp_table.code
```

But as mentioned in the comment, the join could potentially increase the number of rows if in the main table multiple `code_##` match the join criteria in the tmp_table

Comment: Why would a `JOIN` be faster?  I don't see this.

Comment: I've always been kind of confused about which one is faster, and from what I have read, it depends on the execution plan. But in general a join is faster than a subquerry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141278/subqueries-vs-joins/141310#141310

Comment: That answer is misleading (because the correlated subquery can still be the fastest query) and Oracle has a much, much smarter optimizer than MySQL.